# Visual Studio 2017 stops working when certain forms or user controls are clicked

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

At the beginning my project was fine and running but after a while i added more User controls and Windows forms to my project Visual studio started to stop working and restart whenever i click certain windows form design or user control design. I tried many solution but i did not get the answer even i installed and reinstalled visual studio 2017 professional. can someone help me with this situation.
i have tried this solution

> "I've been able to debug some control designer issues by running a second 
>       instance of VS, then from your first VS instance do a "Debug -> Attach to 
>       Process" and pick "devenv".

but its not working for me.

Comment: Things to try, Clean the solution, delete the .suo file, try a `devenv /reset settings`, recreate the project manually being careful to run/build at each step to narrow down what causes it, check your PC specs are sufficient for vs2017

Comment: When you try to debug VS itself, make sure you disable Just My Code in debugging settings. Then you might be able to see what exactly causes VS to stop working. I blogged about it years ago on other troubleshoot ways, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lexli/2009/08/23/when-the-applicationprogram-crashes-on-windows/

Comment: If the form is drawing things via custom code, this could lead to a crash. You could add "if(Loaded) before the drawing code.